# No overload for 'txtSearch_KeyDown' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler'

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a function to check if a user presses enter while the text box is in focus. However im getting this error

> Error 1   No overload for 'txtSearch_KeyDown' matches delegate
>   'System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler'

```
private void txtSearch_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs f)
{
    if (f.KeyCode.Equals(Key.Enter))
    {
```

and this is the xaml code for the text box

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" Canvas.Left="144" Canvas.Top="190" Width="392" Height="33" " KeyDown=" txtSearch_KeyDown"/>
```

Comment: delete `System.Windows.Forms.` from `f`s type to wireup the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the wrong parameter-signature, because of a type mismatch.
It is `System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs` not `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs`.

Comment: thanks , changed the parameter and used key instead of keycode, it worked .

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of the handler must be of the type

```
System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs
```

and not

```
System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs
```

That's why the signature does not match the KeyEventHandler signature.